# MYSQL date compare query

Tags: mysql, date, compare

I'm trying to return a list of vehicles where I know they are not already booked for a current date range. I have a tblVehicles table:

```
ID     Name
1      BMW
2      Merc
3      Land Rover
4      Hummer
5      Convertable
```

I also have a table (tblDiary) that holds all the dates that vehicle is being used:

```
ID     VehicleId     startDate     endDate
1      1             2016-06-20    2016-06-22
2      1             2016-06-24    2016-06-24
3      2             2016-05-01    2016-06-05
```

So I'm trying to write a query where I want to find vehicles that are available between 2016-06-21 & 2016-06-23. So, in this instance the desired result would be:

```
ID     Name
2      Merc
3      Land Rover
4      Hummer
5      Convertable
```

What the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblVehicles v
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    tblDiary d
        WHERE   d.vehicleId = v.id
                AND endDate >= '2016-06-21'
                AND startDate <= '2016-06-23'
        )
```

Comment: I messed it up in my (now deleted) answer, this one is perfect. +1

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks very much. Should I put an index on the diray table to speed up the query?

Comment: @JamesPrivett: yes, on `(vehicleId, endDate)`.